# Docker with Go cli project

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile

I use the following docker file which works as expected 
The project is a `cli` and when I run command `docker run -it cli` 
I got error from the cli (which is ok since  the entry point is just running fzr ENTRYPOINT ["./fzr”])

Typically I run in on my machine like `fzr -help` or `fzr version` etc

I want that when I use command like `docker run -it cli` that I will be able to run commands inside the container

like `fzr -help`  and  `fzr version`, how can I do that ?

```
FROM golang:1.10.5 AS build-env


ADD https://github.com/golang/dep/releases/download/v0.4.2/dep-linux-amd64 /usr/bin/dep
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/dep

RUN mkdir -p $GOPATH/src/github.com/fzr
WORKDIR  $GOPATH/src/github.com/fzr


COPY Gopkg.toml Gopkg.lock ./

# install project dep
RUN dep ensure 

COPY . ./

RUN  go build  -o /fzr

FROM scratch
COPY --from=build-env /fzr ./
ENTRYPOINT ["./fzr"]
```

Comment: `docker exec -it --rm cli fzr version`

Comment: What’s actually going wrong?  What’s the actual `docker run` command and its actual output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR;
docker run -it cli version

If you set ENTRYPOINT to your binary then everything that you pass after image name will be used as arg to that binary. If for some reason you need to overwrite entrypoint use --entrypoint flag to docker run.

Comment: Since it’s a `FROM scratch` image, there’s nothing else you can possibly set the entrypoint to.  You cannot, for example, get a shell in the container because there’s no `/bin/sh`.